# В JS onclick=function срабатывает только один раз

Tags: javascript

Есть ссылки:

```
<a href="" target="_blank">Ссылка 1</a>
<a href="" target="_blank">Ссылка 2</a>
<a href="" target="_blank">Ссылка 3</a>
```

При клике по первой ссылке открывается в новом окне, а сама ссылка должна удаляться.
Для этого написал такой код:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a")[0].onclick=function(){this.remove();}
```

Получается такой ответ:

```
<a href="" target="_blank">Ссылка 2</a>
<a href="" target="_blank">Ссылка 3</a>
```

Все как нужно. Но при втором клике (по Ссылка 2) почему-то не действует.

Как делать так, чтобы клик срабатывал каждый раз?

Comment: очевидно привязаться к `onclick` у всех ссылок, а не только у первой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А для чего там `[0]`, по вашему? В JS счет начинается с нуля, а `document.querySelectorAll` возвращает нумерованный список элементов. К каждому из элементов можно обращаться через `[номер]`. Вы добавляли обработчик только на нулевой элемент.

Чтобы вручную это всё не писать, существуют циклы:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(function(anchor) {
  anchor.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.remove();
  });
})
```

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank">Ссылка 1</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank">Ссылка 2</a>
<a href="#" target="_blank">Ссылка 3</a>
```

Или, классический:

```
let anchor = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for( let i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++ ) {
  anchor[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.remove();
  });
}
```

---

http://learn.javascript.ru/

 https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/